# General formula for standard error of the regression coefficients

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error

Can this formula be used for calculating standard error of the regression coefficients?

$$ SE(\hat{\beta}_{j})^{2} = (1 / (1 - R_{j}^{2})) * (\sigma^{2} / \sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{ij} - \overline{x_{j}})^{2}) $$

Where $\hat{\beta}_{j}$ is the estimated regression coefficient

$R_{j}^{2}$ is from the regression of $x_{j}$ on all other explanatory variables

$\sigma^{2}$ is the variance of the error term

And how it is used with intercept as $ x_{ij} = \overline{x_{j}}  = 1$ and that will result in division by zero.

Comment: could you write more clearly? for example, 1/1 =1? $\hat\beta$ $\sigma^2$, $\R^2$ ... where are they come from?

Comment: @user158565 the question is edited.

Comment: Could you show explicitly--perhaps with a tiny example--how you think a division by zero might arise?

Comment: @whuber the vector of features of the intercept consists only of ones, so the average will be one and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_{ij} - \overline{x_{j}})^{2} = 0$

Comment: And doesn't that forcibly demonstrate your formula cannot be correct?

Comment: It may be correct for all coefficients except the intercept that's why i'm asking if it's correct or not and if it is can be applied to all coefficients including intercept and how.
This formula from Applied Social Science Statistics course week 7 slides by Brandon Stewart princeton university.